# Correct way to close a socket and ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, networking, sockets, serialization

I am writing a networked application in Java, to communicate between the client and the server I am using serialized objects to represent data/commands and sending them through object output/input streams.

I am having problems cleanly closing the connections, I assume that I am missing something fundamental that I do not really know about, I've never used sockets with serialization before.

What ever order I try to shutdown the connection (close client first, close server first) a `ConnectionReset` exception is thrown.  I cannot catch this exception as the client runs in another thread to the rest of the program constantly listening for messages, this must be done, as in Java `socket.read()` is a blocking method.

What is the correct way to close a socket that I am using to send objects?

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial from Javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html) can help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to send your listener (whether client or server, it doesn't matter) some kind of signal to stop listening for more data. Here is a very simple example:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()));

while (true) {
    Object obj = ois.readObject();

    if (obj instanceof String) {
        if ((String)obj).equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // handle object
}

ois.close();
sock.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought to notify my program of the quitting, I guessed the TCP would do that.

I think as Avi said it was that I was waiting for input while I closed the socket, by alerting the client i can tell it to stop waiting for input.

Comment: You don't need to close `ObjectInputStream`, docs tells: `Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.`

Answer (score 2):

You should probably not be waiting to read() from a socket, while the other end is closing it. In a good network protocol, the client can inform the server that it has nothing more to write (maybe by sending it a special close character) before closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectInputStream.readObject()` will throw `EOFException` if the peer has finished sending objects and closed the connection. You must be ignoring it.

Answer (score -1):

you can implement a protocol of yours over the TCP/IP protocol. Header part of the packets using this protocol will signify different types of packets like- connection packet, data packet, close-connection packet etc.

Comment: Err,no, he is using Serialization.